# Creating Default Value in Form Input Field

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I have a form and I want to use JavaScript to pre-fill a text input, however the code I have so far isn't working, nothing shows up in the input box. Any help would be amazing!

HTML

```
<p><label for="numb">Text</label><input type="text" name="numb" id="numb" required="required"></p>
```

JavaScript

```
window.onload = addText();

function addText(){

document.getElementById("numb").value = "Test";
}
```

Comment: That is working for me. Check it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code works for me - my guess is that you have this javascript in the head and it is running before the input element has been created / rendered into the DOM - move your javascript to the end of the document just before the closing body tag and it should work.

and a small thing - you should close your input tag:

```
<input type="text" name="numb" id="numb" required="required" />
```

Comment: I see, when I put it at the bottom of my HTML document it works. But when I put it in a separate JS file it doesn't work.

Comment: how are you calling it into the html page?

Comment: Using <script>src</script> tags with a link to the js file. Could it be that since the procedure is running onload, it is running before the form is actually loaded?

Comment: well - the correct syntax for calling an external js file - such as  <script src="js/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script> - note that the src is not between the scipt tags and put that at the bottom of hte page as well

Comment: Fixed, I tried running it not onload and it is working fine, thanks for your help!

Comment: fantastic -glad I could help - happy coding

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onload = addText();

function addText() {
   document.getElementById("numb").value = "Test";
}
```

```html
<p>
   <label for="numb">Text</label>
   <input type="text" name="numb" id="numb" required="required">
</p>
```